# Help with how to handle Json/php array data

Tags: php, json

I have the following code

```
$getchats = $api->call("getLatestChats");
echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_values($getchats));
echo '</pre>';
```

which gives me the following results..

```
Array
(
[0] => success
[1] => getLatestChats
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [message] => type /ch g
                [time] => 1311806596
                [player] => mattsnod
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [message] => im good
                [time] => 1311806601
                [player] => lueroi01
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [message] => im good
                [time] => 1311806606
                [player] => lueroi01
            )
```

I know I can use

```
print_r(var_dump($getchats));
```

to get it into a PHP array, but im having trouble figuring out how to work with this data better.

in the php array, its like this

```
array(3) {
  ["result"]=>
  string(7) "success"
  ["source"]=>
  string(14) "getLatestChats"
  ["success"]=>
  array(50) {
[0]=>
array(3) {
  ["message"]=>
  string(4) "yes?"
  ["time"]=>
  int(1311806791)
  ["player"]=>
  string(8) "mattsnod"
}
[1]=>
array(3) {
  ["message"]=>
  string(10) "um hold on"
  ["time"]=>
  int(1311806796)
  ["player"]=>
  string(8) "mattsnod"
}
```

This is a very general question, but how could I use a foreach or while to work with this data as Im not having much luck. Im sure Im overlooking something, but my head is hurting now. Ive been googling and reading all morning.

after some more playing, this is close to what im wanting..

```
foreach($getchats as $chat_on=>$data){
//echo "<b>$chat_on</b><br>";
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
    //echo "$key - $value<br>";
    foreach($value as $key2=>$value2){
        echo "$key2 - $value2<br>";

    }
}
}
```

now to figure out how to manipulate these individually or call as $key2[message] so that i can convert the time stamp and format differently.

message - rlly?
time - 1311809089
player - m0terb0nd

Ultimately, this accomplished what I wanted..

```
foreach($getchats as $chat_on=>$data){
    foreach($data as $key=>$value){
            $date = date("h:i a", $value['time']);
            echo "($date) $value[player]: $value[message]<BR><BR>";
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `success` an `array(50)` if there are only two elements inside of it?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? 'how could I use a foreach or while to work with this data' - you haven't said how you would like to work with the data. Are you trying to work with each element of `success`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($getchats->success as $chat) {
   echo $chat['message'] . "<br>";
   echo $chat['time'] . "<br>";
   echo $chat['player'] . "<br>";    
}
```

Some reference on foreach can be found here - http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: This produces nothing for me unfortunately, tried with and without json_decode on the var

Comment: If this produces nothing, why was it marked as correct? Does it work?

Answer (score 1):

It's an array... access the data like you would in any other array.

```
echo $getchats[2][0]['msg']; // produces: "type /ch g"
echo $getchats[0]; // produces "success"
```

Comment: Ideally, I want to run through the array. Like i would with a while statement pulling data from mysql.

Comment: I missed the array_values() you'd used in your print_r. That basically strips off one level of addressing in th eoutput. Try a plain-jane `print_r($getchats)` which will reveal the full array structure.